# Show help message if any command line argument equals /?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wish to write a Windows Batch script that first tests to see if any of the command line arguments are equal to `/?`. If so, it displays the help message and terminates, otherwise it executes the rest of the script code. I have tried the following:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
  IF "%%A" == "/?" (
    ECHO This is the help message
    GOTO:EOF
  )
)

ECHO This is the rest of the script
```

This doesn't seem to work. If I change the script to:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
  ECHO %%A
)

ECHO This is the rest of the script
```

and call it as `testif.bat arg1 /? arg2` I get the following output:

```
arg1
arg2
This is the rest of the script
```

The `FOR` loop appears be ignoring the `/?` argument. Can anyone suggest an approach to this problem that works?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
@echo off

IF [%1]==[/?] GOTO :help

echo %* |find "/?" > nul
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO :main

:help
ECHO You need help my friend
GOTO :end

:main
ECHO Lets do some work

:end
```

Thanks to @jeb for pointing out the error if only /? arg provided

Comment: If I start this with `myBatch.bat /?` the `echo %*` will expand to `echo /?` which will echo the complete help of the echo command to the pipe

Comment: You could place `echo Args: %*` instead of `echo %*` to avoid the `/?` issue @jeb mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a FOR loop, but use the following instead:

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
IF "%1" == "/?" (
    ECHO This is the help message
    GOTO:EOF
)
SHIFT
GOTO Loop

:Continue
ECHO This is the rest of the script

:EOF
```

Comment: Problem is, unless the argument list contains `/?`, I need to maintain all of the arguments so they are available to the rest of the script. The above approach doesn't do this.